# Why doesn't yes fill up the buffer?

Tags: command-line, bash

Say I do something like `yes | apt-get install foo`. I know that `yes` will non-stop print a bunch of `y\n`'s to stdout. But `apt-get` can only process a few of those. Why doesn't `yes` fill up the buffer? Does it actually only print a `y\n` when requested by `apt-get`?

Comment: Which buffer are you talking about? How do you know it isn't filled up?

Answer (score 2):

**N.B. this is not a complete answer, but I'm keeping it here, mainly because there are good comments below.**

> Does it actually only print a `y\n` when requested by `apt-get`?

Yes. 
The right-hand side of pipes work at the same time as the left-hand side is producing output. Further, the left-side won't go to "completion" unless required. For example, the following will create an infinite loop, writing to the terminal until killed.

```
while true; do echo foo; done
```

However, the following will print out 10 lines, then exit gracefully.

```
while true; do echo foo; done | head
```

Once the `head` command completes, the left-hand side of the pipe doesn't need to work any more, and the "infinite" loop is no more.

Comment: Actually, no. Check with `strace`. `yes` prints a bunch of `y\n` together.

Comment: @muru I'm not really sure how to use strace, but since `yes|head` terminates cleanly, wouldn't we assume the same thing is happening here?

Comment: It terminates cleanly all right (as in no visible error is seen), but that doesn't mean `yes` didn't try to print more: https://gist.github.com/murukeshm/6a7b5d2b49f2d817ffac

Comment: @muru Ah okay. Good point. Still, would you think that the amount of repetition would be limited by the presence of the pipe? I'm not sure about my logic now. I wonder if the amount of repetition is limited by the length of time it takes to complete `apt-get`.

Comment: Yes, the time matters. I have updated the gist with another test. The amount of repetition doesn't seem to depend on the pipe, though (unless you consider involuntary exit forced by SIGPIPE).

Comment: @muru Nice. Okay, so I should probably delete this answer, but I think there are interesting comments here. What do you recommend?

Comment: Nah, you should keep it. You can try out these commands as a starting point for some experiments of your own, and see where it takes you. For example, increasing the time beyond a certain limit doesn't affect the number of bytes printed, so I think that's the buffer size (16*4096 = 64k).

Comment: @muru Okay thanks. That's interesting that the pipe does restrict it somewhat. I suppose it makes sense to allow the output to progress a bit, so the input potentially doesn't have to wait too long.